# Only pro players would buy that kind of expensive tennis paddle - a hypothetical usage to soften the tone?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditionals

**Example 1**

Dialogue

> A: I want to buy that tennis racket.

> B: Only pro players **would** buy that kind of expensive tennis racket.

**Question 1**
Is the "would" here a hypothetical usage to soften the tone?

**Question 2**
Does this kind of usage imply an if-clause?

Comment: Please check terms like tennis racket before posting.

Comment: Why do you want to "soften the tone"? Is the context that your friend doesn't have a nice racket/racquet? If you want to express that even a pro might not have that racket there are ways of indicating that, but it's about probability not tone.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not to soften the tone, nor does it imply 'if'. It just means that the kind of person most likely to buy that model of racquet is a professional player.

Comment: Thank you. However, does the "would" introduce a hypothetical situation? What kind of usage is the "would" here?

Comment: See definition B1 [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would) - _used to refer to a situation that you can imagine happening_.

Comment: I see you asked [a related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/331831/implied-conditionals-questions-only-pro-gamers-would-go-for-an-expensive-pc) and got a different answer. You could turn it into a conditional - "I would only buy a racquet like that if I were a professional player" - but I don't see this sentence as one.

Comment: It's less definite than "Only pro players will buy that kind of expensive tennis racket". It's expressing possibility.